# How to run gulp tasks in terminal

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am a beginner in gulp. I have created a task named task1 in gulp.js and when i tried to execute that task using "gulp task1" in command line,  Its opening the gulp.js file  on brackets editor rather than  executing in command line. Can somebody help me in solving this problem

The code in my gulp file is

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var jscs = require('gulp-jscs');


gulp.task('task1', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(['./src/**/x.js', './*.js'])
        .pipe(jscs())
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', {
            verbose: true
        }));

})
```

Comment: Your file should be named gulpfile.js. Then you do gulp task1 in the terminal

Comment: have you installed gulp?

Comment: @arun what happens when you do `gulp -v`? Does it show you the gulp version?

Comment: Yes its worked by changing gulp.js to gulpfile.js

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you install Gulp on NPM?. 
If not, do the following.

```
$ npm install gulp
$ npm install jshint gulp-jshint --save-dev
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-jscs
```

In case it's not installed, try to:

```
$ sudo npm install -g gulp
$ sudo npm install -g jshint gulp-jshint --save-dev
$ sudo npm install -g --save-dev gulp-jscs
```

After completing the installation, try `gulp` on terminal (Remember that you must be in the same directory of the file).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to making sure you have gulp *globally* installed, make sure your gulp file is named `*gulpfile.js*` and that is in the same directory as where you are running `gulp`. Then simply run `gulp task1`. If you run `gulp` without anything else, the default task will run (you can write a task named "default" which will be run in this case.

Answer (score 2):

1. install gulpJS
2. export the task1 in the gulpFile.js

```js
module.exports = task1
```

3. run the below command in terminal

```sh
gulp task1
```

or

```sh
gulp
```

Answer (score -2):

Install [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) globally and run the gulp command from the folder the 'gulpfile.js' is located

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp -D
```